# kurento utils not found?

Tags: node.js, kurento-media-server

I installed kurento media server on a ubuntu machine.

I instanciated the hello world example provided here : https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/node/tutorial-helloworld.html

When running the application in Chrome, I'm getting the following error and the video stream is not shown in the browser.

**GET ipadress:8443/bower_components/kurento-utils/js/kurento-utils.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

Does anyone know if any module may be missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem by build the browser version of the library [kurento_utils] according to this - https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/features/kurento_utils_js.html#build-for-browser

Also, you need to install **grunt** and change 22 line in */static/index.html*

from
`<script src="bower_components/kurento-utils/js/kurento-utils.js"></script>`

to
`<script src="bower_components/kurento-utils/dist/kurento-utils.js"></script>`